# Does Grails have a mechanism to provide an automatic, default rendering of a form based on a corresponding Domain class?

Tags: forms, grails

I've look around and see a few plugins that do this, but I'm surprised it's not built into the language, outside of the scaffolding.

In Django, for example, you can say

```
<form action="/contact/" method="POST">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and get a reasonable form for a model, based on the model definitions and additional names and hints you can supply.

Is there any equivalent way of doing this in Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not within grails core.

The closest I can think of would be:

```
class BookController {
   def scaffold = true
}
```

then

```
<g:include controller="Book" action="edit"/>
```

You can also call

```
<g:render template="/book/edit" model="[book:mybook]"/>
```

but the functionality you've described does not exist.